# Orchard: Creating a user from the register screen NOT dashboard

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.6

Hey Guys…So im using Orchard CMS 1.6 and instead of creating a user/role from the dashboard, I would like the user to register from the home page.

This is done by leaving the ‘username’ and ‘password’ field blank on the home page and clicking ‘Sign In’. They are then navigated to a ‘Log On’ page which displays a ‘Register link’.

This allows the user to enter 4 fields to create an account. ‘Username, Email, Password, and confirm password’. I would like to add additional fields to this form but am having no luck.

I’ve tried to install the profile, Users personal Info, and extended Reg modules.
These add additional fields to creating a user, when the user is created from the dashboard. (Users/ Add new user)…but not to the register screen.

Does anyone have any idea how to add fields to the register screen(access from the home page)?
Thanks for any replies…

Comment: Your first sentence says you want users to register from the home page, and later you say you want to add more fields to the register form where it already exists. Which is it?

Comment: Sorry I dont understand how that is difficult? I want to use the existing register from accessed from the home page....BUT i would like to add additional fields to it...address etc...any ideas?

Comment: There are several profile modules on the gallery, and in principle that is what they should be doing. If not, I would contact the author of the module.

Comment: thanks Bert...I know there are several modules that do this and I have tried them...'profile, Users personal Info, and extended Reg modules' but all these modules add extra fields to the user/role register form when a new user/role is created from the dashboard. I want to add extra fields to the other register form which is accessed from the home page????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tl;dr:

Check out: [Extended Registration](http://gallery.orchardproject.net/List/Modules/Orchard.Module.itWORKS.ExtendedRegistration)

Details:

You can accomplish this with combination of the [Profile module](http://gallery.orchardproject.net/List/Modules/Orchard.Module.Contrib.Profile) and the [Extended Registration module](http://gallery.orchardproject.net/List/Modules/Orchard.Module.itWORKS.ExtendedRegistration). By default, the Registration page  (Found in Orchard.Users) is hard-coded to display only the four fields you mentioned. Extended Registration takes the Profile part from the Profile module and also displays it on the Registration page.

Build out your registration field to however you want by extending the User content type, though it sounds like you have done this since you have access to these fields via New User in the Admin dashboard.

**Note:** Extended Registration requires the Profile module.

Comment: ok thanks for the advice...ended up creating my own controller and view and rolling with that...cheers for the reply though